# python nested attributes encapsulation

Tags: python, properties, attributes, nested, encapsulation

I have some question about encapsulation nested attributes in python. Let's assume few classes: 
Here we have a main class (DataWrapper) that includes two more classes: InnerWrapper1 and InnerWrapper2. Both inner wrappers includes two attributes.

```
class DataWrapper(object):     
    @property
    def inner_wrapper1(self): 
        return self.__inner_wrapper1
    @inner_wrapper1.setter
    def inner_wrapper1(self, value): 
        self.__inner_wrapper1 = value

    @property
    def inner_wrapper2(self): 
        return self.__inner_wrapper2
    @inner_wrapper2.setter
    def inner_wrapper2(self, value): 
        self.__inner_wrapper2 = value

class InnerWrapper1(object):
    @property
    def property1(self): 
        return self.__property1
    @property1.setter
    def property1(self, value): 
        self.__property1 = value

    @property
    def property2(self): 
        return self.__property2
    @property2.setter
    def property2(self, value): 
        self.__property2 = value

class InnerWrapper2(object):
    @property
    def property3(self): 
        return self.__property3
    @property3.setter
    def property3(self, value): 
        self.__property3 = value

    @property
    def property4(self): 
        return self.__property4
    @property4.setter
    def property4(self, value): 
        self.__property4 = value
```

Is it possible to override somehow *getattr* and *setattr* methods to make possible below encapsulation? What I want to achieve is to have an access to those nested attributes from the top class- DataWrapper.

```
data_wrapper = DataWrapper()
data_wrapper.property1 = "abc"
...
var = data_wrapper.property2
...
```

The first thing that came to my mind was to execute *hasattr* in *getattr*, but that gave a maximum recursion depth...

Here's a complete code:

```
class DataWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self):
            self.inner_wrapper1 = InnerWrapper1()
            self.inner_wrapper2 = InnerWrapper2()

    @property
    def inner_wrapper1(self):
            return self.__inner_wrapper1
    @inner_wrapper1.setter
    def inner_wrapper1(self, value):
            self.__inner_wrapper1 = value

    @property
    def inner_wrapper2(self):
            return self.__inner_wrapper2
    @inner_wrapper2.setter
    def inner_wrapper2(self, value):
            self.__inner_wrapper2 = value

    def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
            #if attribute in {'innerwrapper1', 'innerwrapper2'}:
            if attribute in ['inner_wrapper1', 'inner_wrapper2']:
                    return super(DataWrapper, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
            if hasattr(self.inner_wrapper1, attribute):
                return setattr(self.inner_wrapper1, attribute, value)
            elif hasattr(self.inner_wrapper2, attribute):
                return setattr(self.inner_wrapper2, attribute, value)



    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
            try:
                    return getattr(self.inner_wrapper1, attribute)
            except AttributeError: pass

            try:
                    return getattr(self.inner_wrapper2, attribute)
            except AttributeError: pass

class InnerWrapper1(object):
    @property
    def property1(self):
            return self.__property1
    @property1.setter
    def property1(self, value):
            self.__property1 = value

    @property
    def property2(self):
            return self.__property2
    @property2.setter
    def property2(self, value):
            self.__property2 = value

class InnerWrapper2(object):
    @property
    def property3(self):
            return self.__property3
    @property3.setter
    def property3(self, value):
            self.__property3 = value

    @property
    def property4(self):
            return self.__property4
    @property4.setter
    def property4(self, value):
            self.__property4 = value

def main():
    data_wrapper = DataWrapper()
    data_wrapper.property1 = "abc"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The answer is "yes, that is possible". Did you have any problems implementing it? If so, can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Since `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` just take attribute names, you'll need to think how you are going to route attribute access to one or the other inner object. Did you want to hardcode the attributes (`if name in ('property1', 'property2'): # use first inner object`, `else:` # ...)` or did you want to dynamically test for attributes?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add your attempt. If this didn't work for you, what happened instead?

Comment: Hi Martijn. Thanks for a quick response. I've updated my question :)
All right, but what does exactly mean "use"? Because I have a maximum recursion depth error when I invoke getattr inside __ getattr __

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an infinite recursion error because you forgot to take into account setting the `inner_wrapper1` and `inner_wrapper2` attributes in your `__init__` method.

When you do this:

```
self.inner_wrapper1 = InnerWrapper()
```

Python will *also* use your `__setattr__` method. This then tries to use `self.inner_wrapper1` which doesn't yet exist so `__getattr__` is called, which tries to use `self.inner_wrapper1` which doesn't yet exist, and you enter into an infinite recursion loop.

In `__setattr__` delegate attribute setting to the superclass:

```
def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
    if attribute in {'innerwrapper1', 'innerwrapper2'}:
        return super(DataWrapper, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
    if hasattr(self.inner_wrapper1, attribute):
        return setattr(self.inner_wrapper1, attribute, value)
    elif hasattr(self.inner_wrapper2, attribute):
        return setattr(self.inner_wrapper2, attribute, value)
```

If you used a single leading underscore for 'private' attributes (so `_innerwrapper1` and `_innerwrapper2`) you could just test for that:

```
def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
    if attribute[0] == '_':  # private attribute
        return super(DataWrapper, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
```

so you don't have to hardcode a whole set of names.

Since your updated full script uses `__inner_wrapper1` and `__inner_wrapper2` as the actual attribute names, *and* you are using properties, you'll have to adjust your `__setattr__` test to look for *those* names. Because you are using double-underscore names you need to adjust for the [name mangling of such attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

```
def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
    if attribute in {
            'inner_wrapper1', 'inner_wrapper2',
            '_DataWrapper__inner_wrapper1', '_DataWrapper__inner_wrapper2'}:
        return super(DataWrapper, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
```

Unless you are going to subclass `DataWrapper` and must protect your attributes from accidental overriding, I'd avoid using double-underscored names altogether, however. In Pythonic code, you don't worry about other code accessing attributes, there is no concept of truly private attributes.

Using properties is also overkill here; properties don't buy you encapsulation, in Python you'd only use those to simplify the API (replacing a method call with attribute access).

Note that the `hasattr()` tests for the `InnerWrapper*` `property*` attributes will *fail* because you don't have default values:

```
>>> inner = InnerWrapper1()
>>> hasattr(inner, 'property1')
False
```

`hasattr()` doesn't test for properties, it simply tries to access an attribute and if *any* exception is raised it returns `False`:

```
>>> inner = InnerWrapper1()
>>> hasattr(inner, 'property1')
False
>>> inner.property1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 43, in property1
AttributeError: 'InnerWrapper1' object has no attribute '_InnerWrapper1__property1'
>>> inner.property1 = 'foo'
>>> inner.property1
'foo'
>>> hasattr(inner, 'property1')
True
```

By removing all the `@property` objects you can simplify this greatly:

```
class DataWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._inner_wrapper1 = InnerWrapper1()
        self._inner_wrapper2 = InnerWrapper2()

    def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
        if attribute[0] == '_':
            return super(DataWrapper, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
        if hasattr(self._inner_wrapper1, attribute):
            return setattr(self._inner_wrapper1, attribute, value)
        elif hasattr(self._inner_wrapper2, attribute):
            return setattr(self._inner_wrapper2, attribute, value)

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        try:
            return getattr(self._inner_wrapper1, attribute)
        except AttributeError: pass
        return getattr(self._inner_wrapper2, attribute)

class InnerWrapper1(object):
    property1 = None
    property2 = None

class InnerWrapper2(object):
    property3 = None 
    property4 = None
```

Comment: Thanks again! Hmm. I still have an infinite recursion... I have updated my question and pasted the whole script at the end to make it easier to check and execute.

Comment: @Konrad: you don't have an `inner_wrapper1` attribute. You have an `__inner_wrapper1` attribute, *so test for that*. Take into account that by using `__` double underscores you made your life more difficult because Python mangles those names to `_DataWrapper__inner_wrapper1`.

Comment: @Konrad: in other words, you need to either test for `if attribute.startswith('_DataWrapper')` or use `if attribute in ['_DataWrapper__inner_wrapper1', '_DataWrapper__inner_wrapper2']`.

Comment: @Konrad: boy, you do make it hard for yourself. Expanded with why your code doesn't work some more.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Martijn!

Comment: Sure, I will take care of it. Btw, do you think there is generally no point in using python properties?

Comment: You don't need to use properties the way you need to use them in Java or C#, if that is what you are thinking. There are plenty of usecases for properties in Python, but you'd only ever use them if you want to provide an API that uses attributes where you really want to be able to run code to produce the attribute value or need to alter the value being set.